Sample a random subgraph from an undirected, unweighted graph, what's the probability of "every two nodes's distance is at least 3 in the subgraph"?
This may be a problem in sampling theory or graph theory. I have done many research but I still didn't find valid solutions.
I know a simple random sample is representative of the population. Now I wonder if it still works when it's 'restricted' by a social network, which means if there are two nodes' distance is less than 3, it can not be chosen as the sample. I'd like to know under which condition, every two nodes in a simple random sample has distance at least 3 in high probability.
In detail, consider a undirected unweighted graph $G=(V,E)$, where $V=\{1,\dots,n\}$ is the vertex set and E is the edge set. Consider a simple random sample $S\subseteq V$, and let $|S|$ indicate the number of set $S$. Now we ask: under which condition (like the restiction on $|S|$, the pattern in which $G$ goes to infinity, the restriction on $G$, etc),
$$P(d(i,j)\geq3,\forall i,j\in S) \to 1.$$
It is better if there are non-asymptotic properties.

It may relate to the concept of 'independent set' in graph theory.

How is your population graph generated? The answer will be quite sensitive to this.

@ThomasLumley Yeah, you're right. Actually, that's exactly what I want to ask. I'm seeking the condition that can make this results hold.

The question has no definite answer without specifying the probability distribution behind the sampling mechanism (and possibly a prior on  the distribution of edges over the entire graph).

@Xi'an Yeah, I see. But I'm sorry I can not provide more details, because that's exactly what I'm seeking for. To be honest, I'm a rookie in this field. I had hoped there are some off-the-shelf results...

@MattF. Thanks! I mean $d(i,j)$ in a big graph $G$.
